# Ng-repeat toggle, initial state shows first-child and hides the rest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'm currently accomplishing toggling the visibility of items from a collection like so:

```
.terms ng-repeat="term in terms" 
  h1 ng-click="termOpen = !termOpen"
    | {{term.name}}

  .term ng-show="termOpen"
    p Content blah blah
```

The default state of `.term` is hidden. When the heading is clicked the contents of `.term` are revealed.  This works fine, except that I'd like the initial state of the first element to be visible.

I tried `ng-show = '"facetOpen" || "$first"'`, but then I can't toggle the first term so that it's hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ng-init`

```
h1 ng-click="termOpen = !termOpen" ng-init="termOpen=$first"
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for and in nine minutes when I can accept this answer as correct, I surely will.

Answer (score 0):

Plus some  more things, on top of the answer of charlietfl:

1. Since, I think you want to just toggle one of the element and not all element on click of a section, you must modify it to be like:

   ```
   h1 ng-click="term.termOpen = !term.termOpen" ng-init="term.termOpen=$first"
   ```

Now, on this, what will happen is, initially termOpen property of that item will be undefined(so false, except first one), next time on click it will be !undefined so true, on click again it is !true so false.
If you use the same variable, like you have done, then on click of any one section will open all the sections, which I dont think you want to do.

2. You were doing:

   ```
   ng-show = '"facetOpen" || "$first"'
   ```

which will always be true as both are strings (you put them in double quotes, angular thinks of them as strings), it should have been:

```
ng-show = 'facetOpen || $first'
```

where facetOpen is a scope variable. Also, it does not work properly, as first item will always remain open, since its condition is always true.

These are two more things you might want to consider.